# lambda-calculus Church Rosser Theorem and Application Order Reduction

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have a question about an "apparent" contradiction I found in my lesson notes on Application Order Reduction (AOR) and the Church-Rosser Theorem (CRT). I'd like to emphasize that I'm not suggesting there's a real contradiction, and it is most certainly just my lack of understanding of CRT at issue.

Ok here goes. The CRT says that the beta-normal form of a lambda expression can always be reached if one exists regardless of the order in which beta-reduction takes place. But AOR is a beta-reduction policy that can get stuck in an infinite loop, thereby failing to reach the beta-normal form of an expression. Hence the apparent contradiction.

Here's where I think I'm messing up: The apparent contradiction would be resolved (I think) if CRT didn't mean "do reduction in any order you want and you'll always *eventually* reach a reachable beta-normal form" but instead meant "do reduction in any order you want and you'll never reduce your expression down to an expression that prohibits you from reaching a reachable beta-normal form, but just keep in mind that you may need to change up your reducing-order policy in order to actually get there".

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CRT says (in particular) that the beta-normal form is unique. So, if your policy allows you to reach the beta-normal form, then it will be the same form regardless of your policy. It doesn't state that you can reach it using your policy. Check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Rosser_theorem).